# explanation on simple c++ inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    void m1(){ cout << 'A'; }
    virtual void m2(){ cout << 'B'; }
    virtual void m3(){ cout << 'C'; }
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void m1(){ cout << 'D'; }
    void m2(){ cout << 'E'; }
};

class C: public B {
public:
    void m3(){ cout << 'F'; }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    A* a = new B();
    a->m1();
    a->m2();
    a->m3();
    return 0;
}
```

What will be the output? I initially thought that it will be "D E C" but after running the program it was "A E C"

Could one elaborate what is going on behind this line of code:

```
A* a = new B();
```

Comment: m1() is not virtual in the base class A. Fixing that should give the expected result.

Comment: You added the keyword `virtual, do you know what is it for ??

Comment: -1 This is pretty silly; you're obviously just randomly guessing. Did you think that `virtual` had no purpose? Didn't spot the pattern in the output you're getting? Or read your C++ book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtual member functions are dispatched based on the *dynamic* (run-time) type of the object. Non-virtual member functions are dispatched based on the *static* (compile-time) type of the object.

```
A *a = new B();
```

`a` points to an object whose dynamic type is `B`. The static type of `a` is `A*`, however, which means that the static type of `*a` is `A`.

Virtual functions (`m2` and `m3`) are dispatched based on the dynamic type, so `B::m2` and `B::m3` are called.

Non-virtual functions are dispatched based on the static type. The static type of `*a` is `A`, so `A::m1` is called.

---

What exactly is going on in the `new` line? A new object of type `B` is created dynamically, and the `new` expression returns a pointer to that object (of type `B*`). Then, a derived-to-base conversion is applied to that pointer to convert it to an `A*`, which is used to initialise the variable `a`.

In pseudo-code, showing intermediary steps:

```
B *tmp_b = new B(); // allocate and initialise B object
A *tmp_a = convert_derived_to_base(tmp_b);
A *a = tmp_a;
```

Comment: Fast shots are no match for a steady one. +1!

Comment: so compilator first successfully initialise pointer to class A object: `A *a` and then dynamically initialize pointer to class B object and overrides initialised `A *a` to equal to `B*` ? I need to know what is going on under the hood.

Comment: @tomtom I've added the steps in code form. There's no "overriding" going on.

Answer (score 1):

m1 method is not virtual in class A, it can not be override .m2 is virtual so it override with class B method .

Answer (score 0):

The output will be

```
AEC
```

The reason is that `A::m1` was not declared `virtual`. In this line

```
A* a = new B();
```

You are declaring an `A*` variable named `a`, which is actually an instance of the derived class `B`. This is allowed because "`B` is a type of `A`".

When a function is declared `virtual`, if a derived class defines that function then the one in the base class is overridden with the version in the derived class. So the following calls will be made

```
a->m1();    // A::m1
a->m2();    // B::m2
a->m3();    // A::m3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `Class A` is your parent class, so to override parent class's method you need to make it `virtual` in class A. So that `Class B`'s method will be called. Please see more information on [Virtual Functions](http://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/virtual-functions)

Answer (score 0):

```
void m1(){ cout << 'A'; }
virtual void m2(){ cout << 'B'; }
virtual void m3(){ cout << 'C'; }
```

The output is totally fine as per your programs code.

`void m1(){ cout << 'A';`  is not a virtual function. 
So `a->m1();` calls the base version of `m1` and gives the o/p as `A`.

`m2()` is a virtual function and it has a new implementation inside class B.
`void m2(){ cout << 'E'; }`

So `a->m2();` calls the `class B` version of the `m2` function and gives the output `E`.

There is no new implementation of `m3` inside `class B`. 
So  `a->m3();` calls `m3` which is inherited from `class A`.

To get the o/p as `DEC` you have to just change the `m1` function to a virtual function like below

`class A {
public:
    virtual void m1(){ cout << 'A'; }
    virtual void m2(){ cout << 'B'; }
    virtual void m3(){ cout << 'C'; }
};`